# Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery_storage_v1beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location) in Airflow QA

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm running my DAG in our Airflow environment in dev. Works like a charm. Yet when I pushed it to our QA environment, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name bigquery_storage_v1beta1 from google.cloud
```

Below is the code that is being used to generate it.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()


def markov_model_extraction(staging_table, table_one, table_two, table_three, project):
    '''
       This function retrieves data from the staging table in Big Query and is put into a dataframe.
       The dataframe is then used in order to run a Markov machine learning model. Finally, the Markov model results are extracted into 
       3 dataframes which are then sent to 3 Big Query tables via the pandas_to_gbq function. 
    '''
       
    sql1 = '''
    SELECT * FROM ''' + staging_table
    
    df = client.query(sql1).result().to_dataframe()
```

I don't understand what it could be at this point. How could it possibly work in our dev environment yet, in QA, I get that weird error? If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.